# Check if character is on the wrong place in string

Tags: java

I need to check if a character is on the wrong position in a string. I have a database with a couple of strings in it. My app retrieves a random string and the user needs to guess it. Then when the user has guessed a word, the program has to output a set of numbers like this: `22001`. Where the `2` means that the character is on the right spot, the `0` means that the character is not in the word and the `1` means that the character is in the string but on the wrong place. My problem is that i can't figure out how to implement the third feature.

I hope you can help me...

Code for the two other features:

```
// geraden is selector for substring
// input is input from the user
// charWord[] is charArray of word from database
if (input.substring(geraden).startsWith(Character.toString(charWord[geraden]))){
    System.out.println(Character.toString("2");
} else if (!input.substring(geraden).startsWith(Character.toString(charWord[geraden])) && list.contains(input.substring(geraden))) {
    System.out.println(Character.toString(charInput[geraden]) + ": Niet op de juiste plek");
} else {enter code here
     System.out.println(Character.toString("0");
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that does the first 2 features and attempts the 3rd feature?

Comment: Please read [mcve], create one and post it. Instead of adding comments like: `//geraden is selector for substring` why don't you actually post where is `geraden` declared? Also please post a sample input and output.

Comment: Sorry I'am new to StackOverflow...

Comment: Then please take the [tour], go through the [help], read [ask] and post a proper [mcve]

Comment: What about `hello` and I write `world`, it should return: `01020`? Or should it return `01010`? There are 2 `L`, one in its place, one in a different place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 3rd feature can be achieved with this algorithm:
1- convert both strings to `char[]`
2- check if `chars1[i] != chars2[i]`
3- use   `j = str.indexOf(chars1[i])`
4- `if (j==-1)` : character not found in the word
5- else character is in the wrong place

Comment: Okay, I’ll try it in a bit